# foregoを使うと、condaで作った仮想環境を無視する？

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, foreman

condaで作った仮想環境下で`forego run python **.py`で実行すると、仮想環境にinstallしたModuleがImportErrorになってしまいます。調べても出てこず、困っています。

```
import os
import MeCab #あくまで例示、MeCab以外でもエラーになる。
```

実行結果

```
ImportError: No module named MeCab
ERROR: exit status 1
```

環境は以下の通りです。
OS    :Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
python:3.6.4
conda :4.3.34
forego:Version 20180217041714

~~コードの全体は以下のとおりです。foregoを使う目的はAPIのアクセストークン等を.envファイルから読み込むことです。「pythonクローリング&スクレイピング」にかかれていた方法です。

```
import os
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session #ここがエラー

# 環境変数から認証情報を取得する。
CONSUMER_KEY = os.environ['CONSUMER_KEY']
CONSUMER_SECRET = os.environ['CONSUMER_SECRET']
ACCESS_TOKEN = os.environ['ACCESS_TOKEN']
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = os.environ['ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET']

# 認証情報を使ってOAuth1Sessionオブジェクトを得る。
twitter = OAuth1Session(CONSUMER_KEY,
                        client_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET,
                        resource_owner_key=ACCESS_TOKEN,
                        resource_owner_secret=ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

# ユーザーのタイムラインを取得する。
response = twitter.get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json')

# APIのレスポンスはJSON形式の文字列なので、response.json()でパースしてlistを取得できる。
# statusはツイート（Twitter APIではStatusと呼ばれる）を表すdict。
for status in response.json():
    print('@' + status['user']['screen_name'], status['text'])  # ユーザー名とツイートを表示する。
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forego の[コード](https://github.com/ddollar/forego/blob/4bb213294ff63ed4fc2f095d57e425d9ca18a42b/run.go#L40)によると、`forego run` はインタラクティブなシェル上でコマンドを実行します ([issue #9](https://github.com/ddollar/forego/issues/9) を解決するためのようです)。しかしこの設定のためコマンド実行前に `~/.bashrc` などが呼び出され、`source activate 〇〇` の際に指定された `$PATH` などを上書きしてしまいます。したがって conda で指定した仮想環境が無視されてしまい、ImportError に繋がっています。この動作は [issue #14](https://github.com/ddollar/forego/issues/14) で議論されていますが、想定された挙動のようです。

これをどう解決するかは、なぜ forego の上で Python スクリプトを走らせたいかによりそうです。たとえば「activate して python スクリプトを動かす」ようなシェルスクリプトを作ってそれを `forego run` すると一応動かせますが、環境変数を上書きしているため用途によっては forego を使う意味が無いかもしれません。

```sh
#!/bin/sh

source deactivate
source activate ○○○
python ○○.py
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとう御座います。質問内容のところにも追記しましたが、目的はAPIのアクセストークン等を.envファイルから読み込むことです。書籍「pythonクローリング&スクレイピング」に記載されていた方法を真似しています。